# Problem with signal edge in schematics containing high speed IC switch

Tags: switches, analog, high-speed, edge

I am trying to design the following schematics:

There are two kOhms resistance which are connected serially. One is load and another is device resistance. I need to apply the voltage in a the following way using IC switch

- When voltage on the IC switch is non zero the voltage is applied only
  on the device
- When it is zero the both R_load and R_device connected serially

[image: Schematics]

Since the signal through the resistance is a pulse with duration less than 100 ns I am using a couple of op-Amps for impedance matching (the measurements are carrying out on 1 MOhm oscilloscope channel). So I have to use fast IC switch.

For the first experiment I used constant voltage (~500 mV) applied on both resistance. I see the oscillations at the moment when switch is on or off. How can I remove these oscilltaions? I tried these schematics without op-Amps, and saw the same behaviour.

[image]

I tried on the several switches

- ADG712
- SN74LVC1G3157
- SN74LVC1G66

Comment: Show how you measure, that is, with a gnd antenna or properly low inductance

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your question. I simply connected PCB to the oscilloscope, generator and power supply with coaxial cables and soldered wires respectively.

Comment: Do these glitches also occur at the output of the buffer amplifier? You're switching its load, so it needs to react to that; unless it's very carefully compensated, you'd expect to see some sort of transient there.

Comment: I also tried these schematics without op-Amps, and saw the same behaviour.

Comment: Do you have a 50-ohm termination on your oscilloscope? Many oscilloscopes have a switchable 50 ohm input mode. Otherwise you can use a feed through terminator.

Comment: Yes I have 50 Ohm input mode but I need to work with 1 MOhm.

Comment: So the overshoot does not appear when the oscilloscope input is 50-ohm terminated?

Comment: I didn't check it. I will do it.